# Uncaught TypeError: formeo1.render is not a function error while integrating formeo

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I tried to integrate the form builder called [formeo](http://formeo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) .

in one of the page I am trying to do this

```
function renderDataLayout(result)
        {
            console.log(result);
            var  data_layout = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result).data);
            let renderContainer = document.querySelector('.render-form-editlayout');

            sessionStorage.removeItem('formData');
            sessionStorage.setItem('formData',data_layout);

            let container = document.querySelector('.build-wrap-editlayout');
            var fbOptions = {
                  // dataType: 'json',
                   container: container,
                    allowEdit: true,
                    controls: {
                      groupOrder: [
                      'common',
                      'layout'
                      ]
                    },
                  sessionStorage: true,
                  editPanelOrder: ['attrs', 'options']
                };

            const formeo1 = new window.Formeo(fbOptions);

            console.log(formeo1);
            formeo1.render(renderContainer);

            //sessionStorage.removeItem('formData'); 

        }
```

The error I am getting is this

> Uncaught TypeError: formeo1.render is not a function

I tried to console log the `formeo1` object here is how it looks like

[image]

As you can see the object has the property defined as render still js is throwing error .

What could be the possible problem .

Answer (score 0):

Need to Update the code with below concept

```
 //use this one if your geting the data from JSON file.
   //const formeo1 = new Formeo(formData, JSON.stringify(fbOptions));
   // for yours example use below code
   const formeo1 = new Formeo(formData, fbOptions);  
    console.log(formeo1);
```